# position relative перекрывает нижестоящте элементы

Tags: css, position

```
#container{
    position: relative;
}
#container canvas{
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
}

<div id="container">
    <canvas id="cnvBg" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>
    <canvas id="cnvTop" width="1200" height="700"></canvas>
    
</div>

<div>
    content content content 
</div>
```

почему нижестоящие блоки оказываются под `#container` ? как правильно использовать `relative`? это нужно чтобы канвасы были слоями друг над другом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать **css** свойство `z-index`

Подробнее тут:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index